# Prove that $(g ◦ f)_∗ = g_∗ ◦ f_∗ : H_∗(C_∗) → H_∗(E_∗)$. Also show that $(Id_{C_∗})_∗ = Id_{H∗(C∗)}: H_∗(C_∗) → H_∗(C_∗)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

**Let  $C_∗, D_∗$ and $E_∗$ be the complexes of chains and $f_∗ : C_∗ → D_∗, g_∗ : D_∗ → E_∗$ be two homomorphisms of chain complexes. Prove that $(g ◦ f)_∗ = g_∗ ◦ f_∗ : H_∗(C_∗) → H_∗(E_∗)$.
Also show that $(Id_{C_∗})_∗ = Id_{H∗(C∗)}: H_∗(C_∗) → H_∗(C_∗)$.**

If $\overline{w}\in H_n(C_*)=Z_n(C_*)/B_n(C_*)$ then $f_n(\overline{w})=\overline{f_n(w)}$ and likewise with $g_n$. I have tried to do the following but I do not know if it is ok:

$(g\circ f)_n(\overline{w})=\overline{(g\circ f)_n(w)}=\overline{g_n(f_n(w))}=g_n(f_n(\overline{w}))$

Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you only need to check the definition of the induced morphism between homology is well defined.

Show that $f_*:H_n(C_*)\rightarrow H_n(D_*)$ which sent $\overline {w}$ to $\overline{f_n(w)}$ is well defined.

You need to check if $\overline{w}=\overline{x}$,then$\overline{f_n(w)}=\overline{f_n(x)}$.

If you do this, what you have asked is clear.

Comment: I already proved that this is well defined, why what I asked is clear after this?

Comment: @Nash as you said above,$g_n(f_n(\overline{w}))=g_n(\overline{f_n(w)})=\overline{g_nf_n(w)}=\overline{(gf)_n(w)}=(gf)_n(\overline{w})$

Comment: How could I do for the second question? Could I do the following? $Id_{H_n(C_*)}(\overline{w})=\overline{Id_{H_n(C_*)}(w)}=\overline{w}=(Id_{C_*})_n(\overline{w})$.